# Email macro on Mail for MacOS

Tags: macros, apple-mail

I get receipts to my email which need to go to my book keeping. I would love to semi-automate this process, by adding a button for me somewhere where I can go "THAT's a receipt, email to the right place as the right alias". I have trouble combining the interactivity (me selecting an email) and the automation (forwarding etc). Is there a magic bullet here? I've looked at Mail rules, AppleScript and Shortcuts. Nothing seems quite right. Bonus points if I can bind the selection to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: What's wrong with mail rules? Why can't you use them to match your recepts and automatically put them in the right place?

Comment: They are quite heterogeneous - different sources and different languages, not to mention false positives. Not sure I can concoct a rule which has a good enough hit rate, hence the manual selection. Maybe this is the best option, but I thought there might be a middle ground.

Comment: use multiple rules - one for each kind of receipt rather than trying to write one rule to match everything.